# JavaScript: Push each querySelectorAll result into variable

Tags: javascript

can you see what i'm trying to do here? I want to push some objects into a variable but keep it all tidy and contained.

```
var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('[data-search-toggle]').forEach(function(el) {
      this.push({ 'element': el, 'select': el.dataset });
    });
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work, that's just the concept of what I want, so if I was to console.log `toggles` below this I would get along the lines of:

```
[
  { 
    'element': [Object],
    'select': 'dropdown-search__select--make'
  },
  { 
    'element': [Object],
    'select': 'dropdown-search__select--make'
  },
  { 
    'element': [Object],
    'select': 'dropdown-search__select--make'
  },
]
```

Edit:
Or would I need to do something like this:

```
var tmp;
var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('[data-search-toggle]').forEach(
  tmp.push(function(el) {
    return { 'element': el, 'select': el.dataset };
  })
);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="dropdown-search__radio" name="vehtype" id="dropdown-search__vehtype--cars" value="cars" checked required data-search-toggle="dropdown-search__select--make">
        <label class="dropdown-search__label--radio" for="dropdown-search__vehtype--cars">Cars</label>

        <input type="radio" class="dropdown-search__radio dropdown-search__radio" name="vehtype" id="dropdown-search__vehtype--vans" value="vans" data-search-toggle="dropdown-search__select--make">
        <label class="dropdown-search__label--radio" for="dropdown-search__vehtype--vans">Vans</label>

        <input type="radio" class="dropdown-search__radio dropdown-search__radio" name="vehtype" id="dropdown-search__vehtype--bikes" value="bikes" data-search-toggle="dropdown-search__select--make">
        <label class="dropdown-search__label--radio" for="dropdown-search__vehtype--bikes">Bikes</label>
```

Comment: Share your html that you are running this on so we could test the code on something.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=example Note IE support

Comment: why not just `for` loop?

Comment: @VeeK amended post

Comment: Is it really worth storing `el` *and* `el.dataset` separately considering you can get the `.dataset` property directly from `el`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the result of `querySelectorAll` to an array with the `Array.from` function and pass a map function as the second argument to wrap each of the elements in an object.

```js
const toggles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-search-toggle]'), (el) => {
  return {
    element: el,
    select: el.dataset
  };
});

console.log(toggles);
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="dropdown-search__radio" name="vehtype" id="dropdown-search__vehtype--cars" value="cars" checked required data-search-toggle="dropdown-search__select--make">
<label class="dropdown-search__label--radio" for="dropdown-search__vehtype--cars">Cars</label>

<input type="radio" class="dropdown-search__radio dropdown-search__radio" name="vehtype" id="dropdown-search__vehtype--vans" value="vans" data-search-toggle="dropdown-search__select--make">
<label class="dropdown-search__label--radio" for="dropdown-search__vehtype--vans">Vans</label>

<input type="radio" class="dropdown-search__radio dropdown-search__radio" name="vehtype" id="dropdown-search__vehtype--bikes" value="bikes" data-search-toggle="dropdown-search__select--make">
<label class="dropdown-search__label--radio" for="dropdown-search__vehtype--bikes">Bikes</label>
```

Comment: Note, `Array.from()` has a callback at second parameter which could be used instead of `.map()` `Array.from(<array-like-object>, (el, index) => //do stuff)`

Comment: @guest271314 That's pretty neat. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, perfect!

Comment: `select` property of returned object is a `DOMStringMap`, not requirement described at OP, that is the value of the `data-*` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread element to convert `NodeList` to an `Array`, `.map()` to return an object for each element of array. To get the `.dataset` where property contains `-` characters between word characters, camel case the property reference

```
var toggles = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-search-toggle]")].map(el =>
                ({ "element": el, "select": el.dataset.searchToggle })
              });
```